# クラスのジェネリクスの特殊化の冗長な書き方をなくしたい

Tags: swift, ジェネリクス

```
class Hoge<T: Equatable>: Equatable {
    let e: T

    init(e: T) {
        self.e = e
    }

    static func == (lhs: Hoge<T>, rhs: Hoge<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.e == rhs.e
    }
}

class HogeA: Hoge<Int> {}
class HogeB: Hoge<String> {}

class Foo<T: Equatable, U: Hoge<T>>: Equatable {
    var ee: U

    init(ee: U) {
        self.ee = ee
    }

    static func == (lhs: Foo<T, U>, rhs: Foo<T, U>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.ee == rhs.ee
    }
}

class FooA: Foo<Int, HogeA> {}
class FooB: Foo<String, HogeB> {}

let fooA1 = FooA(ee: HogeA(e: 1))
let fooA2 = FooA(ee: HogeA(e: 2))

let fooB1 = FooB(ee: HogeB(e: "あ"))
let fooB2 = FooB(ee: HogeB(e: "あ"))

print(fooA1 == fooA2)
print(fooB1 == fooB2)
```

上記のコードにおいて

```
class Foo<T: Equatable, U: Hoge<T>>: Equatable {
   ...
}

class FooA: Foo<Int, HogeA> {}
class FooB: Foo<String, HogeB> {}
```

の部分が、特殊化の引数を2つ取って冗長です。

本当は

```
class Foo<U: Hoge<T: Equatable>>: Equatable { // 文法エラー
    ...
}

class FooA: Foo<HogeA> {}
class FooB: Foo<HogeB> {}
```

としたいのですが、Fooの定義をうまく書けません（文法エラー）。
なにかうまい書き方はSwiftに用意されていますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiftの場合、ジェネリッククラスを参照する場合は、必ずジェネリックパラメータを決定してやる(型推論で決定できる場合は省略できるが、そうでなければ明示)必要があるので、`Hoge<T>`のようにパラメータをジェネリックなままにしておきたいと言うときには、ご質問に掲載されたように2つジェネリックパラメータを使う書き方しかないように思います。(私が思いつかないだけかもしれませんが…。)

完全に同じ制約と言うわけにはいきませんが、プロトコルを使えば、こんな感じには書けます。

```
protocol HogeProtocol: class, Equatable {
    associatedtype E: Equatable

    var e: E {get}

    init(e: E)

}
extension HogeProtocol {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.e == rhs.e
    }
}
class Hoge<T: Equatable>: HogeProtocol {
    typealias E = T

    let e: T

    required init(e: T) {
        self.e = e
    }
}

class HogeA: Hoge<Int> {}
class HogeB: Hoge<String> {}

class Foo<U: HogeProtocol>: Equatable {
    var ee: U

    init(ee: U) {
        self.ee = ee
    }

    static func == (lhs: Foo<U>, rhs: Foo<U>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.ee == rhs.ee
    }
}

class FooA: Foo<HogeA> {}
class FooB: Foo<HogeB> {}

let fooA1 = FooA(ee: HogeA(e: 1))
let fooA2 = FooA(ee: HogeA(e: 2))

let fooB1 = FooB(ee: HogeB(e: "あ"))
let fooB2 = FooB(ee: HogeB(e: "あ"))

print(fooA1 == fooA2) //->false
print(fooB1 == fooB2) //->true
```

`associatedtype`付きのプロトコルを使うことにより、`HogeProtocol.E`のような情報をジェネリックパラメータ(元コードの`Foo`側の`T`)に宣言する必要がなくなります。

Answer (score 1):

ではこうですかね？

```swift
protocol HogeProtocol: Equatable {

    associatedtype Value
}

class Hoge<T: Equatable>: HogeProtocol {

    typealias Value = T

    let e: T

    init(e: T) {
        self.e = e
    }

    static func == (lhs: Hoge<T>, rhs: Hoge<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.e == rhs.e
    }
}

class Foo<T: HogeProtocol>: Equatable {

    var ee: T

    init(ee: T) {
        self.ee = ee
    }

    static func == (lhs: Foo<T>, rhs: Foo<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.ee == rhs.ee
    }
}
class HogeA: Hoge<Int> {}
class HogeB: Hoge<String> {}

class FooA: Foo<HogeA> {}
class FooB: Foo<HogeB> {}


let fooA1 = FooA(ee: HogeA(e: 1))
let fooA2 = FooA(ee: HogeA(e: 2))

let fooB1 = FooB(ee: HogeB(e: "あ"))
let fooB2 = FooB(ee: HogeB(e: "あ"))

print(fooA1 == fooA2)
print(fooB1 == fooB2)
```

---

こういうのは出来ますけど目的とは違います？

```swift
class Hoge<T: Equatable>: Equatable {
    let e: T

    init(e: T) {
        self.e = e
    }

    static func == (lhs: Hoge<T>, rhs: Hoge<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.e == rhs.e
    }
}

class Foo<T: Equatable>: Equatable {
    var ee: Hoge<T>

    init(ee: Hoge<T>) {
        self.ee = ee
    }

    static func == (lhs: Foo<T>, rhs: Foo<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.ee == rhs.ee
    }
}


let fooA1 = Foo(ee: Hoge(e: 1))
let fooA2 = Foo(ee: Hoge(e: 2))

let fooB1 = Foo(ee: Hoge(e: "あ"))
let fooB2 = Foo(ee: Hoge(e: "あ"))

print(fooA1 == fooA2)
print(fooB1 == fooB2)
```

Comment: 目的と違います。Hoge, Fooともにサブクラスを作ることを想定しています。

Comment: ありゃ。かぶっちゃった....